# Remove unwanted characters like \ from url

Tags: android

I am uploading image in an android app and storing it in my online server.

Now I want to display this image on the users profile in the android app. And to do that I have written a code which takes the image url as a param. However since I am using `Slim` framework for the php API the url that is returned is like this `http:\/\/somehost\/foldername\/uploads\/image.jpg` if I feed this url to my method in the Android end I get an exception coz of the url.

However if I feed it the url like this `http://somehost/foldername/uploads/image.jpg` then it works fine.

I tried to use this code to remove the `\` from the url

`img_path = img_path.replace('/',' ');` but it will replace the `\` with a whitespace which will again give incorrect URL.

How do I filter the url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a string as parameter instead of a char. This allows you to replace it with an empty string:

```
img_path = img_path.replace("\\","");
```